# How to add today's date if cell is empty, and if not skip to next column?

Tags: date, if-statement, offset, is-empty

Im a complete VBA noob and im trying to do what seems to be a simple thing.

The purpose of my code is to make a button where it checks to see if the cell is **not** empty, it should offset to the next column and if it is empty, then it should add todays date.
So each day I press the button it adds a new date next to the old one.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
Private Sub New_Date_Click()
ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Select
If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(0,1)

Else
ActiveCell.Value = Date
End Sub
```

It gives me an error message that an Equal sign is missing on row 4 where the offset is.

[What My sheet looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTyNb.png)

Answer (score 0):

A person on another forum answered.

Here is how the code could work:

```
Sub New_Date_Click()
  Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).Value = Date
End Sub
```

I was really overthinking it.

Shoutout to Fluff on mrexcel!